# How exactly to set up and use environment variables on a Mac?

Tags: java, macos, terminal, environment-variables

What is the proper (2021 way) of creating a permanent environment variable on a Mac (macOS Big Sur) and then use it within a Java project.

There are many very old posts regarding this topic. None of them seem to work properly nowadays.

1. How to add a permanent environment value (through terminal)?
2. And how can I use it in a Java code?

I'm also not sure how I was able to add my `testvar=testvalue` to the list, because I tried so many files (although it seems none of them worked), by adding `export testvar=testvalue` to the following files:

- /etc/paths
- ~/.bashrc
- ~/.bash_profile
- ~/.profile
- /etc/profile

Also after inserting it into each file I used `source {file}`.

So at this point I have no idea which is the proper way to create and have it permanently, and being able to use it in my Java code.

So far, I can print the variables into the terminal like this:

```
printenv
```

My variables are getting listed, example:

```
testvar=testvalue
```

In my Java code, I get **null** when using:

```
System.getenv("testvar")
```

However using an other variable names that were not created by me, but the macOS system (eg. "USER") prints the value as expected.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do it with [export](https://mamk2118.medium.com/setting-up-environment-variables-in-macos-mojave-and-mac-os-catalina-27ea1bb032f3)?

Comment: there are "multiple ways" and multiple files you can insert it into,
problem is, none of the worked, I tried them all.
most of these infos are from stackoverflow posts that are 7 -10 -12 years old.

So as in the main question,
which file i should insert "export testvar=testvalue" to be able to use it in the java application with System.getenv("testvar")
since even if my added variable shows in terminal's "printenv" I still get a null when trying to use it in the java code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-on-os-x

Answer (score 30):

macOS Big Sur uses [**zsh**](https://zsh.sourceforge.io) as the default login shell and interactive shell.

If you’re using a Bash profile, such as to set environment variables, aliases, or path variables, you should switch to using a zsh equivalent.

For example:

- `.zprofile` is equivalent to `.bash_profile` and runs at login, including over SSH
- `.zshrc` is equivalent to `.bashrc` and runs for each new Terminal session

You can create `.zprofile` and enter the enter the environment variables there.

---

[*Reference*](https://mamk2118.medium.com/setting-up-environment-variables-in-macos-mojave-and-mac-os-catalina-27ea1bb032f3)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I will try to find some time to test it, and update here with the results.

Comment: I followed this but it doesn't work as my go app still returns an empty variable value after setting the variable first. What's odd is that `env` shows the variables I set.

Comment: I had success on Big Sur with permanent environment variables by creating `.zprofile` and adding entries like this inside `export [variable_name]=[variable_value]`.   Also Helpful: [How to Set Environment Variables in MacOS](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/set-environment-variable-mac)

Comment: The `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, `.zprofile` and `.zshrc` no longer seem to work in `Big Sur 11.6.5` but did on my system on `Big Sur 11.4`

Answer (score 10):

you can edit zprofile using the following command

```
sudo nano ~/.zprofile
```

and add your PATH variable.

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.9
# The original version is saved in .zprofile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

to add multiple values to the PATH variable, just add more **PATH** keys. For example, this is how I added multiple path variables in my M1 mac Monterey

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.9
# The original version is saved in .zprofile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:${PATH}"
PATH="/Users/<name>/.local/bin"
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export PATH
```

Comment: Works great on the latest M2 macs :)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the shell which you are using. For Big Sur, the standard shell is **zsh**, which might explain why `.bashrc` and other bash-related configuration files did not work. If you want to set environment variables for your account in zsh, try to create a `~/.zshenv` file and put the variable declarations there.

See also: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Files.html#Files

Comment: Thanks! I will check it, and mark it as answer if I succeed. ( I will need a few days to be able to have time working on this again)